# Angular route results in 404 - cannot GET

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set urls with angulars ui-router so that I may go to a base url OR go to a the same base url + parameter. So - I can either go to /test or /test/1 and it will go to the same page - the only difference being the url parameters.  So I have this so far:

```
 .state('test', {
    url: '/test',
    templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
    controller: 'testCtrl'
})
.state('testState', {
    url: '/test/:id',
    templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
    controller: 'testCtrl'
});
```

`/test` seems to work fine, but when I type in `test/1`, it displays `cannot GET`. Is this because I am typing the url by hand instead of using ui-routers internal linking (ui-sref). I say this because I notice that when I just type in `/test`, it's the same thing as well. However, the test and home clicks work fine when I use the links on the page set up with ui-sref.  I'd like to be able to share the URL for `test/:id`, as this will be a web app where people logged in can share links.

Also - is there a better way to setup the test and testState into 1 state perhaps? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not on the Angular side, but rather your server (Node I am guessing based on the response wording).  Node/express/whatever doesn't know which file to server for test/1.  Try relaxing your routing scheme. By that I mean, set up the code so that any request for, say `test*` resolves to the same file as `test/`.  Here's an example in an express app:

```
/**
 * For any GET that we can't resolve to a static file, assume it's 
 * an attempt to go to an angular route
 */
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(path_to_indexfile);
});
```

Update (after discussion):

Alternatively you can turn off html5 mode- then you don't need to worry about telling your server how to deal with `/test/1`--angular will use `/test/#!/1` which shouldn't cause an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and yes it is node! I am not familiar with what you mean when you say relax the routing scheme, could you elaborate? I am using a grunt task (grunt-connect) to just run a little local dev server right now.

Comment: Glad that was useful; I added an example. Put it after your code for serving static files so you don't break everything :)

Comment: I am just using the grunt task right now - there isn't even a server.js set up, do you know if there is a way to handle it in the task itself (grunt-connect)?

Comment: OR perhaps maybe there is a better task for testing this stuff - i just want to be able to type in a dynamic url (locally) and have it found, ui-routes doesn't seem to like this currently. Thanks!

Comment: In that case I would recommend turning off html5 mode and using hashbang syntax.  That way you don't need to worry about telling your server how to deal with `/test/1`--angular will use `/test/#!/1` which shouldn't cause an issue.  I prefer hashbang syntax over html5 mode for this exact reason.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options for you, using one state "/test/:id" and then the parameter is optional you can call /test/1 or /test/.

If you want to enable /test you will need another state.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6LZwRIPgdjyM6MoP5xFr?p=preview) with all the options, working.
As AlexMA mentioned seems like you didn't post the problematic code so I cant fix your example.

This config is working for your request:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider
    .state('view', {
            url: '/view/:inboxId',
            templateUrl: 'tpl.view.html',
            controller: 'viewCtrl'
        }).

        state('view_root', {
            url: '/view',
            templateUrl: 'tpl.view.html',
            controller: 'viewCtrl'
        })

})
.controller('viewCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
  $scope.state = $state.current;
  $scope.params = $stateParams;
})
```